# How to merge overlapping shapes while keeping the layer order in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app, icon

I am designing an icon for card decks. What I did is to stack five rectangles with white fill as shown below.

[image]

I am wondering how to make the white fillings transparent while keeping the stack overlapping looking? I have tried Union and Subtract, but it didn't really work.

Comment: You put good effort into your question. But to me it is still unclear what you want to achieve. Consider making a (manual) preview of your desired outcome; maybe even a hand-sketch. If you make the white fill transparent, then you only got the outlines - and how can that look like overlapping, especially since all your outlines are the same colour? If we can see better what you want, you will get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

I hope someone has a quicker / neater way to do this but here is one way that will give you the effect you are looking for.

With your file as it is displayed above. Select one of the rectangles (not the top one). Double click on the shape itself to allow you to edit the path. Click on the path everywhere it goes under another rectangle to add new vector handles in those places. Then use the scissors tool to cut away the segments of line that would be hidden behind the other rectangle(s). Do this for the four rectangles that are behind others and leave the top one alone.